# Getting "Specified cast is not valid" error while downloading the image using unity RestClient package

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to download an image from the URL but it gives me the "Specified cast is not valid" error, using the [Rest Client](https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient) Package. Here is my code please correct me on what I'm doing wrong:

```
public void DownloadImage(string fileUrl, string name)
{
   
    RestClient.Get(new RequestHelper {
        Uri = fileUrl,
        // DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerFile(imagePath + filename),
        Method = "GET",
        DefaultContentType = true,
        EnableDebug = true,
    }).Then(res =>
    {
        Texture2D tex = ((DownloadHandlerTexture) res.Request.downloadHandler).texture;
        
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(tex.width / 2, tex.height / 2));
        if (img != null)
        {
            img.overrideSprite = sprite;
            img.preserveAspect = true;
        }
        
    }).Catch(err => {
        Debug.Log(err.Message);
        Debug.Log("url: " + fileUrl);
    });
}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception? When you debugged, what was the type of the object you were trying to cast? Why exactly do you think it should be a different type?

Comment: Why is the `DownloadHandler` line commented out? Why isn't it creating a `DownloadHandlerTexture` if that is what you want to use?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes you are right I should use DownloadHandlerTexture. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it silly me to ignore the basic thing.

Here is the code:

```
public void DownloadImage(string fileUrl, string name)
    {
       
        RestClient.Get(new RequestHelper {
            Uri = fileUrl,
            DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerTexture(true),
            Method = "GET",
            DefaultContentType = true,
            EnableDebug = true,
        }).Then(res =>
        {
            Texture2D tex = ((DownloadHandlerTexture) res.Request.downloadHandler).texture;
            
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(tex.width / 2, tex.height / 2));
            if (img != null)
            {
                img.overrideSprite = sprite;
                img.preserveAspect = true;
            }
            
        }).Catch(err => {
            Debug.Log(err.Message);
            Debug.Log("url: " + fileUrl);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful. You can mark it so that it can help more people.